# cannot find Array Controller in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, nsarraycontroller, core-data

I'm just starting to use core data in my iphone app.
I have created my Entity (measure) with 2 property (date, value).
According to the tutos I'm reading, I then need to create an Array Controller in Interface Builder. The thing is... I cannot find it in IB. Is there something to configure to have this type of controller in the list ?
Thanks,
Luc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArrayController` is not available in iOS, only on the Mac.

Comment: argh... I was following the Hildegass book and thought this was available on iOS too :) Thanks